# MySQL large relational query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a few tables:

**letter_mail**

```
index   
sent    
from    
to  
template    
public  
stamp   
stationery  
title   
content     
opened
```

**letter_user**

```
index   
username    
password
```

ALL the rows in letter_mail are relational, except for index,public and opened, to another table.

From and To in letter_mail corresponds to the index of letter_user. What i want is to pull all the data from the database, preferably in one query if possible. A * Select on a `letter_mail` row will yield a result much like this:

```
index:1     
sent: 2013-10-03    
from:1  
to:2    
template:1  
public:1    
stamp:1     
stationery:1    
title: 1    
content: 1  
opened : 0
```

What i need, is for the information above to be filled with data from the related tables and be `JSON` encoded. And look somewhat like this:

```
index:1     
sent: 2013-10-03    
from: {1, John}     
to: {2, Jane}   
template: {index: 1, template: "standard template", url: "template_name"}   
public: 0       
stamp: {index: 1, stamp: "standard stamp", url: "some/url"}     
stationery: {index: 1, stamp: "standard stationery", url: "some/url"}       
title: {index: 1, title: "some title"}      
content: {index: 1, content: "some text content"}       
opened : 0
```

Is this completely crazy? Should i break the query into several bits or maybe collate everything into one table all together?

Please tell if you need more information :)

**Solution is this**:

```
select 
  mail.index,
  mail.sent,
  mail.opened,
  mail.public, 
  FromU.username as FromUser, 
  ToU.username as ToUser, 
  T.template as TemplateName, 
  T.url as TemplateURL, 
  S.stamp, 
  S.url as StampURL, 
  S.stamp Stamp, 
  STA.url StationaryURL, 
  Ttl.title, 
  C.content
from 
  letter_mail mail
     JOIN letter_user FromU
        on mail.from = FromU.index 
     JOIN letter_user ToU
        on mail.to = ToU.index 
     JOIN letter_templates T
        on mail.template = T.index
     JOIN letter_stamps S
        on mail.stamp = S.index
     JOIN letter_stationery STA
        on mail.stationery = STA.index 
     JOIN letter_title Ttl
        on mail.title = Ttl.index 
     JOIN letter_content C
        on mail.content = C.index
```

The query works, but doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Not crazy - though you will end up with a good deal of repeated data getting it all at once in a single query.  Whether that is a good idea or not rather depends on the quantity of data and the proximity/connection to the database from the webserver.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid having 9 select queries, but if that is what it takes then...yeah. I could store all the data from the queries inside the master table, but that will also give overhead when querying one thing.

Also if people downvote, please tell why :)

Comment: Wasn't me - some people just mark down any question they consider basic.  Don't put all the data in one table unless it should be, data duplication is to be avoided and is the primary point of a relational database.  You should only need two queries, though one per table.  The linking can be done in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dmcnelis noted, you could consider using joins (more current syntax than older ANSI format of listing tables and applying WHERE criteria).  Here's his version using JOIN syntax.. I've also altered to use shorter alias name references on the tables.  Notice the JOIN/ON shows exactly how tableX relates to tableY instead of buried in a WHERE clause.  This can sometimes cause problems and Cartesian results if you ever OOps forget a where clause.  By doing JOIN, you'll see your criteria on the relationship right away.

```
select 
      L.sent, 
      FromU.username as FromUser, 
      ToU.username as ToUser, 
      T.name as TemplateName, 
      T.url as TemplateURL, 
      L.public, 
      S.stamp, 
      S.url as StampURL, 
      STA.stamp StationaryStamp, 
      STA.url StationaryURL, 
      title.title, 
      C.content, 
      L.opened
   from 
      letter_mail L
         JOIN letter_user FromU
            on L.from = FromU.index 
         JOIN letter_user ToU
            on L.to = ToU.index 
         JOIN template T
            on L.Template = T.index
         JOIN stamp S
            on L.Stamp = S.index
         JOIN stationary STA
            on L.Stationary = STA.index 
         JOIN title
            on L.title = title.index 
         JOIN content C
            on L.Content = C.index
```

Now that all the tables are related, run the query and it gets everything you need.  However, if you are looking for stuff for a certain set of criteria, just add a WHERE clause...  such as

```
WHERE
      L.From = 27
   OR L.To = 27
```

to get any email to or from user 27.

If you only wanted specific stationary, stamp, title, etc, just add as needed.

Comment: Does it even make sense? Or should i restructure the DB?

Comment: There is nothing wrong that I see on how you have things broken down... It is quite common to have many lookup tables in a database.  Think if you have 100,000 records and had to repeat stationary type "Standard Stationary" vs an internal ID 8.  Then you oopsed the spelling?  Fix in the lookup table and you are done.  Your context looks fine.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I've updated the question with your answer and rewarded anyone leading to this answer with upvotes.

Comment: @Eirinn, The bigger element... do you now see the correlation of the JOINS vs the FROM/WHERE combination as shown by dmcnelis, both are valid, however JOINS are more commonly active in practice for querying.

Comment: Hmm it's to prevent scanning a table more than once?

Comment: @Eirinn, no, to logically see the units and their relationships... but, if you DO NOT include your "ON" clause, you'll get Cartesian results where every record in the first table is joined to every table in the second.  Indexes help prevent using table scans, especially when you should always have on the primary key for joins.

Answer (score 1):

In short you can use table aliases to join the same table in multiple times.  I made a couple of assumptions on additional related table names, but essentially you'd end up with a query looking something like this:

```
select 
    sent, from.username, to.username, template_table.name, template_table.url, public, 
    stamp_table.stamp, stamp_table.url, stationary_table.stamp, stationary_table.url, title_table.title, 
    content_table.content, opened
from 
    letter_mail l, 
    letter_user from, 
    letter_user to, 
    template template_table, 
    stamp stamp_table, 
    stationairy stationary_table, 
    title title_table, 
    content content_table
where 
    l.from = from.idex
    and l.to = to.index
    and template = template_table.index
    and stamp = stamp_table.index
    and stationairy = stationary_table.index
    and title = title_table.index
    and content = content_table.index
    where l.index = X
```

The primary problem you'll run into is that this will cause multiple scans of the letter_user table.... that might be avoidable, but is something you should keep in mind, should this database have any real significant size.

The benefit to doing the query like this, as opposed to collating multiple db calls is that you are letting the db do the work it was designed to do, and only making a single call to the database.

Of course this query could be re-worked a little to specifically use joins... but for me, this form is simpler to read and understand, assuming you only want strictly correlated records.